# Save State Of Checked Item In ListView Having Checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

I'm new to android, please help me how to save the state of checkbox,

i.e.

I've ListView with checkbox, three textview and again checkbox. I wish to save the checked state of item(s),

how to save the state of checkbox.
how to save the listitems.

ple give me example.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way but I just save the states off in member variables (well an array really) then on resume of an activity I just set the checked state to whatever was saved off.